# Is Torrification required to hide your IP Address on Skype?

Tags: onion-services

I have been informed that Skype now has a feature to hide IP addresses better.  Does this cover all angles, or is Tor still required to use Skype as safely as possible?

I am not seeking security from Microsoft or a government seeing my IP address, but from other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, torrification is required, because Skype was purchased by Microsoft, which is known for its collaboration with censors. Actually [they even do traffic circumvertion themselves without any notice](http://www.circleid.com/posts/20120917_microsoft_takedown_of_3322_org_a_gigantic_self_goal/)